# Sync Mssql and Elasticsearch using Logstash

Tags: sql-server-2008, elasticsearch, logstash, mssql-jdbc

I try to use logstash, mssql, elasticsearch and kibana. However, I didn't run logstash.
Logstash gives the error below:

> Logstash - java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NameError) missing class name
>   (`org.apache.http.─impl.client.StandardHttpRequestRetryHandler')

How can I correct that error?

Note: Java Jdk and jre version 1.8.0_161, logstash's version is 6.2.2,  elasticsearch version 6.2.2, OS Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is my regional setting of the windows , it is Turkish . The plugin tries to load org.apache.http.impl.client.StandardHttpRequestRetryHa
ndler, with lowercasing the the letter (I) resulting in character (ý) /xFD. Problem will solve by changing regional setting to english .